# Automatilcally transform slider value

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nstextfield, nsslider

I have a slider, bind it with text field.
It is possible automatically transform value to this format:
Example 01 02 03 04 05 06 .. 13 14 15 ..?
Thanks!

Comment: What about using formatter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Anoop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1395941/anoop-vaidya) is right. Create an NSNumberFormatter, and setting its minimumIntegerDigits to 2 will add a leading zero to single-digit numbers.

```
// Create an NSNumberFormatter that will add a leading 0 to single-digit numbers.
NSNumberFormatter* leadingZeroNumberFormatter = [NSNumberFormatter new] ;
leadingZeroNumberFormatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 2 ;
// Attach the NSNumberFormatter to your NSTextField
textField.formatter = leadingZeroNumberFormatter ;
```

The above example will take `6.27` and return `06`. If you'd rather see the `.27`, check out the `fractionDigits` methods in the NSNumberFormatter class reference.

Comment: Big tanks! I think about NSValueTransformer, but NSNumberFormatter easiest way!